# Difference in Wifi connection %'s?

Tags: wireless, display, signal

This is something I've wondered about for a long time...Ubuntu 16.04 using Cinnamon. On a tower computer.

In the action bar I have the Wifi icon. It shows that I'm currently connected to the local wifi AP. If I hover over it with the mouse, it shows a signal of 59% (at least today it does) signal strength.

Now if I click on that icon, I get the drop down listing of all the available wifi sources nearby. But the wifi AP I'm connected to shows 92%?

So, what is up with that? Everything works, just curious what the difference is in signals those %'s are showing.

Comment: Are you sure it's the same network and not different networks from the same AP, one in 2,4GHz and other in 5GHz, the latter being the one with the weakest signal?

Comment: or it just fluctuates. Mine shows a tool tip and the percentage gets between 49 and 78%.

Comment: I do know that there are other AP's in this RV park that have the same SSID, but I'm in a fairly remote area of the park with one antenna box nearby that my receiver is pointed towards. I have a high gain, directional, 2.4 & 5 GHz USB antenna so I'm pretty sure it's not two different APs with the same name. Not sure how to tell for sure though. But Ubuntu does put a little white ball in front of the attached AP in the drop down so yes, it's the same AP shown in both places.

Comment: I can check both places several times an hour and they never change value much. And they are always different. Occasionally, they will be near each other in value, like 75% and 89%, but that's rare.